# Junit cannot Mock a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, stub

I'm having problem when I try to test a method and mock its dependency with PowerMock and Mockito. I've tried to transform the dependency method into a nonstatic method and to use @Mock annotation and @InjectMocks but with no result at all.

Here is the class and method under test:

```
/* class to be tested */
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

   /* method to be tested */
   @Override
   public String createJwt(String subject, String name, String permission, Date datenow)  throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException{
       Date expDate = datenow;
       expDate.setTime(datenow.getTime()+(300*1000));  //expiration time = 30 minutes

       String token = jwtUtils.generateJwt(subject, expDate, name, permission);
       return token;
   }
}
```

Here there is the Dependency I want to Mock and which I am having troubles mocking:

```
/* Dependency I cannot mock */
public class JwtUtils {

    public static String generateJwt(String subject, Date date, String name, String scope) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setExpiration(date)
            .claim("name", name)
            .claim("scope", scope)
            .signWith(
                    SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,
                    "myPersonalSecretKey12345".getBytes("UTF-8")
            )
            .compact();

       return jwt;
   }
}
```

And here at last, but not least, the test class with the test method which fails.
I have to say that it doesn't even reach the assert method call, but fails at when().thenResult().
I have also to specify that I've tried to use doReturn() and any() as matcher, but with not result.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)          //to run Mockito
@PrepareForTest({JwtUtils.class})           //powerMock annotations tomock classes containing static methods
public class LoginServiceImplTest {

   @InjectMocks
   LoginServiceImpl loginService;          //System under test (SUT)

   @Test
   public void createJwtTest() throws Exception {

       SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       Date expdate = ft.parse("2040-12-12");
       String jwt = JwtUtils.generateJwt("BDAGPP32E08F205K", expdate, "Pippo Baudo", "conduttore");
       //HERE IT'S WHERE IT FAILS:
       when(JwtUtils.generateJwt("BDAGPP32E08F205K", expdate, "Pippo Baudo", "conduttore")).thenReturn(jwt);

       assertThat(loginService.createJwt("BDAGPP32E08F205K", "Pippo Baudo", "conduttore", expdate), is(jwt));
   }
}
```

Here there is the error JUnit and Mockito gives to me:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.    Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>
> at
>   com.example.bytecode.SpringBootJWT.services.LoginServiceImplTest.createJwtTest1(LoginServiceImplTest.java:114)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Try `when(JwtUtils::generateJwt)`

Comment: Also your `createJwt()` method modifies argument `datenow`...!

Comment: thank you, but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. As far as I'm aware, all tests which use PowerMock features must be run with `PowerMockRunner`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such rule that methods in *utility classes* must be `static`!

In fact it is a bad practice because it makes your code highly coupled and inflexible. You problems replacing this dependency are a prove of that.

So instead surrendering to your bad design and using *PowerMock* you should apply *inversion of control* by removing the `static` key word from the method an pass in an instance of that class into your unit, preferably using a *DI framework*.
In that case you could use plain *Mockito* to mock that dependency and had no issues replacing it.